# How to drop columns by criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that `df` is a pandas `DataFrame` object.

> How do I drop all the columns of `df` that contain only `None`, empty strings, or white-space-only strings?

The criterion for dropping could be expressed as those columns where all the values yield `True` when fed to the following test function:

```
lambda x: (x is None) or not re.match('\S', str(x))
```

Comment: would it be an option to loop through the columns and drop when the check is True?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) to apply your function to the elements of the `DataFrame`:

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None] * 4, 'b': list('abc') + [' '],
                            'c': [None] + list('bcd'), 'd': range(7, 11),
                            'e': [' '] * 4})

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
      a  b     c   d  e
0  None  a  None   7   
1  None  b     b   8   
2  None  c     c   9   
3  None        d  10   

In [21]: to_drop = df.applymap(
                     lambda x: (x is None) or not re.match('\S', str(x))).all()

In [22]: df.drop(df.columns[to_drop], axis=1)
Out[22]: 
   b     c   d
0  a  None   7
1  b     b   8
2  c     c   9
3        d  10
```

Comment: `applymap` was the key to getting the `re.match` function to work for me.  It failed when using just `apply`

Comment: Actually I think the OP's question wants **`all`** rather than **`any`**. :)

Comment: @AndyHayden ok I think your are right, I'll update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've got it mostly figured out below, but I'm not too familiar with RegEx in Python yet.  This is the basic approach I would take:

Dummy Data:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
      a  b  c
0  None     1
1     b     2
2     c  x  3
3     d     4
4     e  z  5

In [2]: df.to_dict()
Out[2]:
{'a': {0: None, 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'b': {0: ' ', 1: ' ', 2: 'x', 3: ' ', 4: 'z'},
 'c': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}}
```

Apply a lambda testing for the conditions you want to drop:

```
In [3]: df.apply(lambda x: x.isin([None,""," "]))
Out[3]:
       a      b      c
0   True   True  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False   True  False
4  False  False  False
```

Invoke the `any()` method which tests for True in any of the df columns

```
In [4]: df.apply(lambda x: x.isin([None,""," "])).any()
Out[4]:
a     True
b     True
c    False
```

Index df.columns with the boolean Series from above to get the columns you want to drop:

```
In [5]: drop_cols = df.columns[df.apply(lambda x: x.isin([None,""," "])).any()]

In [6]: drop_cols
Out[6]: Index([a, b], dtype=object)
```

Use the df.drop() method and pass the axis=1 option to operate on the columns:

```
In [7]: df.drop(drop_cols, axis=1)
Out[7]:
   c
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Now if someone with more Pandas/RegEx experience can figure out that piece, I'd say you have a decent solution.

Comment: Actually I think the OP's question wants **`all`** rather than **`any`**. :) It's funny because this is so nearly `df.apply(all)`... [It's definitely worth learning regular expressions](http://xkcd.com/208/).