# Python Pandas find non zero indices

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Hi I'm trying to use pandas to tidy up a DataFrame. It is imported from a spreadsheet and has some empty rows and columns.

I thought I could use

`df.apply(numpy.nonzero(),axis=1)` and `df.apply(numpy.nonzero(),axis=0)` to get the indices of the non-zero columns so that I could remove there inverses from the DataFrame.That gives me a list of tuples I'm not clear how to get at.

`numpy.nonzero(df)` produces an array of all the non-zero values but I'm not sure how to feed that value into an `all()` function.

My question is what would be the best and quickest way of removing those index rows and columns from a DataFrame that are all empty (or all have a value such as N/A)s

Thanks

EDIT example of the source spreadsheet added

```
<bound method DataFrame.head of             0         1         2  3         4         5  6         7         8  9   \
0                                                                                     
1   some title                                                                        
2         date     38477                                                              
3                                                                                     
4                                                                                     
5                   cat1                   cat2                   cat3                
6                      a         b            c         d            e         f      
7                                                                                     
8            Z  167.9404  151.1389      346.197  434.3589     336.7873  80.52901      
9            X   220.683   56.0029     73.73679  428.8939     483.7445  251.1877      
10           C  433.0189  390.1931     251.6636  418.6703     12.21859   113.093      
11                                                                                    
12           V  226.0135  418.1141     310.2038  153.9018     425.7491  73.08073      
13           W   295.146  173.2747     2.187459  401.6453     51.47293   175.387      
14           S  306.9325  157.2772     464.1394   216.248     478.3903   173.948      
15           A  19.86611  73.11554      320.078  199.7598     467.8272  234.0331      
16                                                                                    
17           F   225.511  20.97305     425.8834  190.1625     123.9103  116.3803      
18           R  130.4728  96.08118     428.2007  22.46184     26.34678  359.5625      
19           E  239.1516  439.7733     197.7023  121.6911     195.0169  264.5553      
20           W  227.1557  471.8341     165.3779  151.7552     314.7827  367.0868
```

this is the def I'm using at the moment but it feels very clunky

```
def nulls(x):
    ''' the NULS section to clear all nulls from the 
DataFrame'''
    # Empty Rows
    nr = [i for i in x.index if all(str(k) in '' for k in x.ix[i])]
    # Non Empty Rows
    r = [i for i in x.index if i not in nr]
    # Empty columns
    nc = [j for j in range(x.shape[1]) if all(str(k) in '' for k in x[j])]
    # Non Empty Columns
    c = [j for j in range(x.shape[1]) if j not in nc]
    # Subset the non-empties
    x=x.ix[r,c]
    x=x.reindex()
    return(x)
```

Comment: Your example dataframe is not great. It'd be much more helpful if you posted something that we could *run* (i.e., a 3 column, 3 row dataframe) and could manipulate. Plus, it would clarify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dropna(how='all')` is what you are looking for (generally), but you need to load in your dataframe in such a way that empty cells are treated as `NaN` instead of empty string.  That said, you have a few options here.

If you are sure that everything you want to drop is either the literal empty string (`''`, `None`, `np.NaN`, or `0`) *and* that you don't want to keep `0`, then you can just fill the `NaN` and convert to boolean and check whether the sum is 0. You can tweak depending on how you want to drop.

```
indexer = df.fillna(False).astype(bool)
drop_columns = indexer.sum(0) == 0
keep_rows = indexer.sum(1) != 0

new_df = df.drop(df.columns[drop_columns], axis=1)[keep_rows]
```

However, if you need to check for whitespace, or want to exclude the literal zero, then you should use `applymap` with a function (mostly based on [this StackOverflow answer on dropping None/empty/whitespace columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838945/how-to-drop-columns-by-criteria)) and then do the same thing as above.

```
def is_blank(x):
    return x is None or pd.isnull(x) or bool(str(x).strip())

indexer = df.applymap(is_blank)
```

Personally though, I suggest you add `''` to `na_values` when you load your dataset.

---

#### Brief explanation of  `fillna()` and `astype()`

[`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) lets you "fill" `NA` values with some other value. Here, we fill with False (because `bool(float('nan'))` evaluates to True), but you can fill with any value or with a variety of different methods.  `astype` converts the array from one type to another. So putting `astype(bool)` means that it converts the entire array to either `True` or `False` (which are equivalent to `1` and `0` respectively) and then you can just sum to find the number of `True` values in a row or column.

Comment: Thanks @JeffTratner, that works brilliantly. Would you mind explaining what the df.fillna is doing? I understand (I think) the `df.fillna(False)` but what is the `astype(bool)` doing? How does it know what to treat as an NA? Thanks

Comment: @TahnoonPasha updated the question with some explanation. Best thing to do would be to read the pandas docs for more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DataFrame.dropna()? This won't deal with the zeroes but gets rid of NaN columns and rows.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: thanks @kdamica that will work for the latter, but I actually have a more pressing need to get rid of the zeros.

Comment: Are the cells you want to remove empty or do they contain the value 0?

Comment: Hi @kdamica they are empty

Comment: I think they'll be imported as NaNs, then, so dropna() might do the trick. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi @kdamica, sorry for the slow reply. I tried it and it doesnt work. The blanks are imported as `''`